# jquery ui function problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Really my total hairs gone for it problem.

```
 $('ul#listticker').prepend($('<li><div  class="user-box" id="user_box1">.......</div></li>').fadeIn(2000));

$("ul#listticker li:first").show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
```

It is perfectly working in IE but not working in firefox.

I found solution for it that is

my class user-box is

```
#fbook-iq .user-box {
    width:280px;
    height:41px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    padding:9px;
}
```

if i remove float:left line perfectly working

```
#fbook-iq .user-box {
    width:280px;
    height:41px;
        margin-bottom:1px;
    padding:9px;
}
```

Really i don't know what logical behind it.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Why is the `user-box` class floating left? This points to the `div` element inside the `li`, and I don't quite see any reason for it. If the `float: left` on this element breaks behavior in Firefox, you might try to rather set the `li` containing element to the needed width and height, and leave the `div` element a non-floating block element. It's a work-around, but if it solves your problem, it solves your problem.